# Have more western movies had scenes filmed in Russia since the end of the Cold War?

Tags: film-location, american-cinema, get-smart-2008

I noticed that the 2008 Get Smart film had some of its [scenes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425061/locations) in Russia (and the US). Is this something that's more common after the end of the Cold War compared to during the Cold War?

As a side question, has the end of the Cold War meant more Russian movies with scenes shot in the US?

Comment: Would you believe that there's no questions about the TV series?

Comment: By default I would think the answer would have to be yes, as very few US filmmakers would have been allowed to film anything in the USSR during the cold war.  To be pedantic, the answer would be yes because during the cold war it was the USSR and not Russia.

Comment: @sirjonsnow as a piece of trivia, there was a place called Russia during the Soviet Union: the [Russian Soviet Federative Socialist Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Soviet_Federative_Socialist_Republic)